# How is a Windows COM interface used?

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I am trying to send some data to an application through a COM interface, but I'm not understanding the documentation.

Given the following definition, how would I send a string to this method on a com interface?

```
A Windows COM interface that can be used with most single and multithreading Windows application development environments and languages. It does not have any initialization or finalization routines.

Interface: IXXXXXXTrans
Flags:     (4416) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
GUID:      {A1AED31D-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}

IXXXXXXTrans = interface(IDispatch)
   ['{A1AED31D-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}']
   function FunctionName(const value:WideString):WideString; safecall;
end;
```

This is the entirety of the "Documentation"

I have looked at several of the documentations from MSDN, which do not seem to apply.

I do not have any reference to a dll in the documentation, and the application developers are not available to provide any help.

I have looked at many of the links provided, they do not seem to address this case as many of them assume you have control of both the server and the client. I have only the client and limited documentation, and the server is not a .NET dll so I cannot add it as a reference.

I have tried using this code:

```
            Guid testCLSID = new Guid("A1AED31D-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX");
            Type testType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(testCLSID, true);
            IXXXXXXTrans testTrans = (IXXXXXXTrans )Activator.CreateInstance(desktopType);
            testTrabs.FunctionName("Yes");
```

Which returns

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {A1AED31D-876C-4AA3-AF60-3560062660DF} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

I have also used tlbImp to get a dll to view with ildasm, but I'm not sure where to go from there

Comment: If you are calling from C# you need a runtime callable wrapper to help.  A couple of references that will give you the info you need:   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe(v=vs.110).aspx     https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404285(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, is there any sample code on how to use this? This doesn't seem to show any implementation. The documentation also does not reference any DLL to import as a COM reference or register as a COM server

Comment: This may help:  https://www.codeproject.com/articles/19354/quick-c-cli-learn-c-cli-in-less-than-minutes    You can also google "Runtime callable wrapper"

Comment: It depends on the COM server, but in many cases there is a TLB available or you can create one, and from that Visual Studio will automatically create the necessary run-time wrapper classes. You can also declare them yourself, e.g. using [appropriate attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4w8x20h(v=vs.100).aspx) on class declarations. See marked duplicate for a wealth of information on the topic.